# If a functor preserves finite limits, does it preserve subobjects?

Tags: category-theory

I have just started learning category theory. My question really appears on the title. In other words, can a subobject be seen as some kind of limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism. Then $f : X \to Y$ is a monomorphism if and only if the diagram below is a pullback square,
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
X & \rightarrow & X \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
X & \rightarrow & Y
\end{array}$$
where $X \to X$ is the identity. Thus, any functor that preserves pullback squares preserves monomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks, very clear! So should I, when the word subobject appears, think of it just as a monomorphism, without worrying about the fact that it is actually an equivalence class? Is it always safe?!

Comment: I don't feel the definition of subobject as an equivalence class is very useful.

Comment: I agree with Zhen. If $X$ is an object of a category $C$, then one may define the *category of subobjects* $\mathrm{Sub}(X)$ as the full subcategory of $C \downarrow X$ which consists of monomorphisms $Y \to X$. Actually this category is a preorder. Every preorder is equivalent to a poset. In this case, this means that we identify subobjects if there is an isomorphism between them. But of course it is not really important to do so. Isomorphic objects don't have to be replaced with each other. Here it is somehow tempting because the isomorphism is unique.

Comment: Now the statement proven by Zhen means: If $F : C \to D$ is a functor which preserves pullbacks, then it lifts to a functor $\mathrm{Sub}(X) \to \mathrm{Sub}(F(X))$ for every $X \in C$.